# Unable to Insert Record with the Record Type - LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lwc-wire-adapter

I am new to LWC, i have few RecordTypes for the **Service** object, i am trying to insert the record with the record type **(Mobile Service Record Type)**, but with the below code record is getting created with the default RecordType only..

**RecordTypeTest.html-**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={serviceObject} onsuccess={handleServiceCreated}>
        <lightning-input-field field-name={namefield}
                                   onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input-field>                     
        <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Create Account"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

**RecordTypeTest.js:-**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import SERVICE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Service__c';
import SERVICE_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Service__c.Name';

export default class RecordTypeTest extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @api serviceObject = SERVICE_OBJECT;

    @track objectInfo;
    @track namefield = SERVICE_NAME;

    fields = [SERVICE_NAME];

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: SERVICE_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    get recordTypeId() {
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        return Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Mobile Service Record Type');
    }
    handleNameChange(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the complete code of your LWC? If it is you are not using the recordTypeId you got from wire adapter in the `lightning-record-edit-form` using `record-type-id` attribute. Please refer to the documentation about r[ecord-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation).

If this is not the complete code, please share your full to understand the problem better.

**Note:** *I am only writing my comments/suggestions as an Answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question.*

Comment: Hi Naga, i have added the record-type-id={recordTypeId} in the cmp, it is working fine, thanks